# Finding birth/baptism records for Prussian ancestor born around 1840?

Tags: germany, birth-records, 1840s, 1830s, prussia

My GreatGrandfather listed in his US census that he was born in Prussia around 1840.  I believe that I traced him to Lubeck.

How can I find birth/baptism records for Lubeck/Travemunde for about that time?

Answer (score 2):

If he was Protestan/Lutherian you could try https://www.archion.de/en/

It is an online archive of the german protestant churches, where you can find a lot (albeit not all) church records.

Answer (score 2):

In general, a good starting point is often the [FamilySearch Research Wiki](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/L%C3%BCbeck_Civil_Registration_-_Vital_Records) page for the place you are interested in.

---

In the case of Lübeck, the FamilySearch Research Wiki page for [civil registration](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/L%C3%BCbeck_Civil_Registration_-_Vital_Records) shows that indexes and images for [births](https://search.ancestry.com/search/db.aspx?dbid=1573) are available for the period 1811 - 1875, which covers your period of interest.

The page for [church records](https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/L%C3%BCbeck_Church_Records) shows that there is a list of parishes available (as the article notes,  the main article is in German, but the chart on page 2 of the linked pdf shows the existing parish registers.

---

If your ancestor was still in Lübeck in 1857, it is worth noting that there was a [census](https://search.ancestry.com/search/db.aspx?dbid=1940) in that year, which might have recorded your ancestor and members of his immediate family.